# Huge difference in requests per second between a route with html template and one without in Golang

Tags: go

I have the following Go app:

```
package main

import (
  "pat"
  "log"
  "net/http"
  "html/template"
  "runtime"
)

func main() {
  runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)
  route := pat.New()
  route.Get("/user/:name/profile", http.HandlerFunc(profile))
  route.Get("/", http.HandlerFunc(front))

  http.Handle("/", route)

  http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/",
  http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))

  log.Println("Listening on port 5000...")
  http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil)
}

func profile(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
  // Catch url request query and store it in "params" var
  params := request.URL.Query()
  // Get "name" url param
  name := params.Get(":name")
  response.Write([]byte("Hello " + name))
}

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age string
}

var Templates *template.Template
const LayoutPath string = "templates/layout.html"

func front(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    user := Person{Name: "testuser", Age: "39"}
  Templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("themes/*.html"))
  Templates.ExecuteTemplate(response, "layout", user)
}
```

When you visit `127.0.0.1:5000/user/yourname/profile` you get 16000 requests per second while visiting `127.0.0.1:5000` (front) only 2800 requests per second..

What am I doing wrong here?

the "layout" template is like this

```
{{define "layout"}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content=""><meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/stylesheet.css/' />
  </head>
  <body>

  {{template "body" .}}

  </body>

    {{end}}
```

and the "body"

```
{{define "body"}}
<p>test body</p>
{{end}}
```

I also tried changing GOMAXPROCS without any difference if not worse.

I was using Python and got far more requests with a full finished app and I'm disappointed that it outperforms Go like this.. the reason I switched to Go was for performance and because I wanted to get 8-10000 requests per second.

Can you help me where I'm doing it wrong? Should I switch to C/C++ for better performance?

Comment: If you do the the test in C++ I'm pretty sure you will get similar results, you're comparing returning a string to parsing multiple files in each request then executing a template.

Comment: The answer about how to avoid redundantly loading templates is right, but also want to say if these numbers seem bad, you're probably worrying too much about CPU time, too early. You don't go from 0 to 1k req/s--3.6 million hits/hour--overnight, or running on two cores. The hard part is usually making a complete, well-tested service and getting enough people to use it that you ever encounter scaling problems; once you do, adding more front-end Web servers is usually the easy part.

Comment: Generally, both your time and servers have a cost. In this case, I mainly mean performance is worrisome either when your requests/sec has fallen well under millions of hits per hour on 2 cores, or your traffic has gotten up closer to that level. Anyway, question answered and performance improvement attained, so it's all good.

Answer (score 6):

You are parsing multiple files every time, the tests are no where equivalent, parsing the template once will give you better performance.

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age string
}

var tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("themes/*.html"))
const LayoutPath string = "templates/layout.html"

func front(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    user := Person{Name: "testuser", Age: "39"}
    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(response, "layout", user)
}
```